# Increase the height of specific tableview cell dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've currently multiple items in tableView cell .I want to increase the height of cell when text condition is matched like if name = "john" then increase the height of cell without disturbing another cell. I want to achieve this screenshot result
[image]

My current code is

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView == tableOrder {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
            self.tableOrderHeight.constant = self.tableOrder.contentSize.height
            //self.tableOrderHeight.constant = (6 * 80)
         }
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath ) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: PriceTVCell.self)) as? PriceTVCell else {return UITableViewCell()}
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: use `heightForRowAt` func to increase scpecific cell height.

Answer (score 0):

first get the index of the row you want to increase the height and use the delegate function heightForRowAt.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
if indexPath.row == customRow {
   return 100.0;//Choose your custom row height
  }
}
```